# Regarding a complex map

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. Let $[a,b]$ denote the line segment joining $a$ and $b$.
Can anyone tell how does the map $\frac{z-a}{z-b}$ map $
[a,b)$ to the negative real axis?

I know that any point $z_0$ in $[a,b]$ will be of the form $ta+(1-t)b,\;\;0\leq t\leq1$. Now $z_0-a=ta+(1-t)b-a= (t-1)(a-b)$. And $(t-1)<0$.

Comment: Since $\frac{z-a}{z-b}$ is undefined when $z=b$, the question makes no sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I ask this question with reference to time 22:16 in the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld2HP8mbRmc&lc=UgzIpuWreV0mKre51Xd4AaABAg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=(1-t)a+tb$, with $t\in[0,1)$, then$$\frac{z-a}{z-b}=\frac{-ta+tb}{(1-t)a-(1-t)b}=\frac{-t}{1-t}\in(-\infty,0].$$